spring jpms module exited
anyone can explain to me why my spring jpms module exited ?
my code is too simple :
package ir.moke.module.spring;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "ir.moke.module.spring.api")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

Controller class:
package ir.moke.module.spring.api;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestApi {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello dear !";
    }
}

this is module-info.java
module spring.jpms {
    requires spring.web;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.core;

    opens ir.moke.module.spring to spring.core, spring.beans,spring.context ;
    opens ir.moke.module.spring.api to spring.beans, spring.web;
}

pom.xml :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ir.moke.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Compiler -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>21</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- copy compiled jar file to target/lib , only needed for test jpms -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Copy dependencies , only needed for test jpms -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

I compiled project with this command :
mvn -DskipTests clean compile package

and try to run  :
> java --module-path target/lib -m spring.jpms/ir.moke.module.spring.Application     
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.3.0)

[2024-06-03 22:19:05.264] - 85702 INFO [main] --- ir.moke.module.spring.Application: Starting Application using Java 21 with PID 85702 (/home/mah454/Downloads/spring/target/lib/spring-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by mah454 in /home/mah454/Downloads/spring)
[2024-06-03 22:19:05.293] - 85702 INFO [main] --- ir.moke.module.spring.Application: No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[2024-06-03 22:19:05.860] - 85702 INFO [main] --- ir.moke.module.spring.Application: Started Application in 0.888 seconds (process running for 1.197)

Spring application just exited without any error or exception !
how to debug this problem ?

Update Question:
I changed log level to DEBUG:
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.0)

[2024-06-04 12:44:19.891] - 21151 INFO [main] --- org.example.Main: Starting Main using Java 21 with PID 21151 (/home/mah454/Downloads/spring-jpms/target/modules/spring-jpms-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by mah454 in /home/mah454/Downloads/spring-jpms)
[2024-06-04 12:44:19.915] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.example.Main: Running with Spring Boot, Spring
[2024-06-04 12:44:19.917] - 21151 INFO [main] --- org.example.Main: No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[2024-06-04 12:44:19.918] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication: Loading source class org.example.Main
[2024-06-04 12:44:19.965] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@157853da
[2024-06-04 12:44:19.978] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
[2024-06-04 12:44:19.989] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.076] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner: Identified candidate component class: URL [jar:file:///home/mah454/Downloads/spring-jpms/target/modules/spring-jpms-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/org/example/Sample.class]
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.382] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.388] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.sql.init.dependency.DatabaseInitializationDependencyConfigurer$DependsOnDatabaseInitializationPostProcessor'
...
...
...
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.447] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.450] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'spring.jackson-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.452] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.BoundConfigurationProperties'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.470] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Autowiring by type from bean name 'standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer' via factory method to bean named 'spring.jackson-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.473] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'parameterNamesModule'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.473] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$ParameterNamesModuleConfiguration'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.476] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'jsonMixinModule'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.477] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonMixinConfiguration'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.478] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'jsonMixinModuleEntries'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.479] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Autowiring by type from bean name 'jsonMixinModuleEntries' via factory method to bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@157853da'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.480] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationPackages: @EnableAutoConfiguration was declared on a class in the package 'org.example'. Automatic @Repository and @Entity scanning is enabled.
...
...
...
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.567] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.569] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'spring.info-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoProperties'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.571] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Autowiring by type from bean name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration' via constructor to bean named 'spring.info-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoProperties'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.572] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.572] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'spring.sql.init-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sql.init.SqlInitializationProperties'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.577] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ssl.SslAutoConfiguration'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.577] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'sslPropertiesSslBundleRegistrar'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.578] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'spring.ssl-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ssl.SslProperties'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.579] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Autowiring by type from bean name 'sslPropertiesSslBundleRegistrar' via factory method to bean named 'spring.ssl-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ssl.SslProperties'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.580] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'sslBundleRegistry'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.581] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Autowiring by type from bean name 'sslBundleRegistry' via factory method to bean named 'sslPropertiesSslBundleRegistrar'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.584] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.585] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'taskExecutorBuilder'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.586] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'spring.task.execution-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskExecutionProperties'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.587] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Autowiring by type from bean name 'taskExecutorBuilder' via factory method to bean named 'spring.task.execution-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskExecutionProperties'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.590] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskSchedulingAutoConfiguration'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.592] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'taskSchedulerBuilder'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.593] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'spring.task.scheduling-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskSchedulingProperties'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.595] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Autowiring by type from bean name 'taskSchedulerBuilder' via factory method to bean named 'spring.task.scheduling-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskSchedulingProperties'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.597] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory: Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.client.RestTemplateAutoConfiguration'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.609] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor: Starting beans in phase -2147483647
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.610] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor: Successfully started bean 'springBootLoggingLifecycle'
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.623] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger: 


============================
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT
============================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   AopAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.aop.auto=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   AopAutoConfiguration.ClassProxyingConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class 'org.aspectj.weaver.Advice' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   ApplicationAvailabilityAutoConfiguration#applicationAvailability matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.availability.ApplicationAvailability; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   GenericCacheConfiguration matched:
      - Cache org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.GenericCacheConfiguration automatic cache type (CacheCondition)

   ...
   ...
   ...

Negative matches:
-----------------

   ActiveMQAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   AopAutoConfiguration.AspectJAutoProxyingConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.aspectj.weaver.Advice' (OnClassCondition)

   ArtemisAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory' (OnClassCondition)

         ...
         ...
         ...
         ...
         
         
   TaskSchedulingAutoConfiguration#scheduledBeanLazyInitializationExcludeFilter:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (names: org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans named org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor (OnBeanCondition)

   TaskSchedulingAutoConfiguration#taskScheduler:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (names: org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans named org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor (OnBeanCondition)

   ThymeleafAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.thymeleaf.spring6.SpringTemplateEngine' (OnClassCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' (OnClassCondition)

   UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' (OnClassCondition)

   ValidationAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'jakarta.validation.executable.ExecutableValidator' (OnClassCondition)

   WebClientAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient' (OnClassCondition)

   WebFluxAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.reactive.config.WebFluxConfigurer' (OnClassCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'jakarta.servlet.Servlet' (OnClassCondition)

   WebServiceTemplateAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.oxm.Marshaller' (OnClassCondition)

   WebServicesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet' (OnClassCondition)

   WebSessionIdResolverAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'reactor.core.publisher.Mono' (OnClassCondition)

   WebSocketMessagingAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer' (OnClassCondition)

   WebSocketReactiveAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'jakarta.servlet.Servlet' (OnClassCondition)

   WebSocketServletAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'jakarta.servlet.Servlet' (OnClassCondition)

   XADataSourceAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'jakarta.transaction.TransactionManager' (OnClassCondition)


Exclusions:
-----------

    None


Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ssl.SslAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.LifecycleAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.availability.ApplicationAvailabilityAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration



[2024-06-04 12:44:20.633] - 21151 INFO [main] --- org.example.Main: Started Main in 1.053 seconds (process running for 1.41)
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.635] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.boot.availability.ApplicationAvailabilityBean: Application availability state LivenessState changed to CORRECT
[2024-06-04 12:44:20.637] - 21151 FINE [main] --- org.springframework.boot.availability.ApplicationAvailabilityBean: Application availability state ReadinessState changed to ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC


this simple code does work without any problem on spring 2.1.2.RELEASE and java 11.
but in spring 3.3.0 does not work !

Remove all your plugins and just add spring-boot-maven-plugin to build the right jar. Specify java.version as a property in your pom.xml instead of overriding the compiler plugin.

I can confirm that with the changes suggested by @M.Deinum and then using mvn package followed by java -jar target/spring-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  works. Not sure about the particular need to execute with the complete command line. On the other hand I agree, the logs are not much of help here in terms of what is wrong with your current approach.

Another possibly related thread.

I want to have jpms project with spring framework , i know normal jar file working without any problem but why application exited with java --module-path target/lib -m spring.jpms/ir.moke.module.spring.Application
